# network interfaces not running

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, ethernet

I am trying to get my LAN port up and running. The available interfaces on my system are :

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# USB device 0x:0x (ath9k_htc)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e8:de:27:0f:79:8c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x15d8 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="94:c6:91:1f:26:d4", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

As you can see wlan0 (an external USB wifi dongle) and eth0 are available. However after plugging in my LAN cable  and running ifconfig gives the following :

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  


          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:140959 (140.9 KB)  TX bytes:140959 (140.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:de:27:0f:79:8c  
          inet addr:192.168.100.235  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fe0f:798c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11072061 (11.0 MB)  TX bytes:1096635 (1.0 MB)
```

You can see the eth0 is not listed. I tried bring up interface:

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ sudo ifup eth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Cannot find device "eth0"
Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

The contents of /etc/network/interfaces

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Finally for completion here is output of lshw:

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc100000-dc101fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc200000-dc21ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: e8:de:27:0f:79:8c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.4.0-130-generic firmware=1.4 ip=192.168.100.235 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ uname -a
Linux user-NUC7i5BNH 4.4.0-130-generic #156~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 13:51:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Available Intel drivers are :

```
user@user-NUC7i5BNH:~$ ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel
e1000  e1000e  e100.ko  fm10k  i40e  i40evf  igb  igbvf  ixgb  ixgbe  ixgbevf
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the drivers are loaded?

```
sudo lsmod | egrep 'igb|ixgb|e1000'
```

The available intel network driver modules should be located under

```
/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel
```

If none of the intel drivers are loaded, you can use modprobe or insmod to load them one by one and checking after each load if the NIC is recognized.
Following files can help determining the problem:

- /var/log/syslog
- /var/log/udev
- /var/log/dmesg
- /var/log/kern.log

Comment: Hi @Blacky. I have edited the post to include available network drivers. I loaded each of them with `sudo modprobe <module_name>` , checked if they are loaded with `sudo lsmod | grep <module_name>` and then ran `ifconfig` to check if the eth interface is up but this did not work. Should I restart network interfaces after every kernel module insertion ?

Comment: If the module is correctly loaded, the eth0 interface should show up in "ifconfig -a"
Can you try commenting out the "SUBSYSTEM=..." line for eth0 in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and rebooting?